# What does keySet().toArray(new Double[0]) do?

Tags: java, dictionary

What does the following return do? And how can I use that value:

```
private Map<Double, String> theLabels = new HashMap<Double, String>();

public Double[] getTheLabels() {
  return theLabels.keySet().toArray(new Double[0]);
  }
```

Is this correct?

```
Double[] aD = theClassInQuestion.getTheLabels();
```

Thanks in advance.

HJW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converts the set of keys into an array of `Double`s. The parameter `new Double[0]` is needed for the compiler/JVM to infer the correct type for the array to be returned. (If the array parameter is long enough to hold all key values, it will be used, otherwise a new array of the same runtime type will be created with the required length.)

Here is [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

Your assignment of the return value is correct.

Answer (score 6):

It is correct, however, unless the theLabels is empty, the reallocation of the array is forced. Here is an alternative:

```
public Double[] getTheLabels() {
    return theLabels.keySet().toArray(new Double[theLabels.size()]);
}
```